# Testing issues due to credentials (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem with a project I recently cloned. When I run the `rspec` or `rails test` commands, everything works. On the other hand, if I want to run `rails test:system`, an error appears:

```
rails test:system
/Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:208:in `rescue in _decrypt': ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:185:in `_decrypt'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:159:in `decrypt_and_verify'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in `decrypt_and_verify'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:92:in `decrypt'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:54:in `read'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:48:in `options'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:303:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:342:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/robin/freelance-projects/xxxx/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/robin/freelance-projects/xxxx/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<main>'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/freelance-projects/xxxx/test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:47:in `block in load_tests'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:47:in `each'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:47:in `load_tests'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:40:in `run'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/commands/test/test_command.rb:33:in `perform'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
/Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:203:in `final': OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:203:in `_decrypt'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:159:in `decrypt_and_verify'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:22:in `decrypt_and_verify'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:92:in `decrypt'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:54:in `read'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:48:in `options'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:303:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:342:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/robin/freelance-projects/xxxx/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require_relative'
    from /Users/robin/freelance-projects/xxxx/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<main>'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/freelance-projects/xxxx/test/channels/application_cable/connection_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:47:in `block in load_tests'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:47:in `each'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:47:in `load_tests'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:40:in `run'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/commands/test/test_command.rb:33:in `perform'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:100:in `register'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/robin/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I of course thought of a problem of credentials keys. The master key is the same as my colleagues. I deleted `config/credentials.yml.enc` and `config/credentials/test.yml.enc`, then I did the command `EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit` and `EDITOR=nano rails credentials:edit -e test`, in order to recreate the files (`config/master.key` is not needed because I have an environment variable RAILS_MASTER_KEY).

After that, the system tests were working, but the others weren't working anymore, with the same error...

I no longer know where to look. I have exactly the same project as my colleagues. I copied/pasted the contents of their `.env`, their master key, the contents of their `config/credentials.yml.enc` and `config/credentials/test.yml.enc` files, but nothing to do, it doesn't want to work. I then reinstalled ruby, the gems and the app, in doubt, but that didn't work either.

Our stack:

`ruby 3.0.3p157`
`rails 7.0.2.3`

Has anyone come across this problem before? Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To solve ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage error in a rails application. Here is what we should do;

- Delete the following files; config/master.key and config/credentails.yml.enc
- Next, run the following command in code editor terminal `EDITOR="mate --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit`
- Solved, now test and see if it is resolved

Thank you and I hope it helps, kindly reach out if you find otherwise

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).